What does it mean for a function to be "unique"?
I"m currently working through Tao's analysis textbook, and was trying to solve the problem...

Exercise 3.5.7. Let $X$, $Y$ be sets, and let $\pi_{X\times
> Y\longrightarrow X}:X\times Y\longrightarrow X$ and $\pi_{X\times
> Y\longrightarrow Y}:X\times Y\longrightarrow Y$ be the maps
$\pi_{X\times Y\longrightarrow X}(x,y):= x$ and $\pi_{X\times
> Y\longrightarrow Y}(x,y):= y$; these maps are known as the co-ordinate
functions on $X \times Y$. Show that for any functions
$f:Z\longrightarrow X$ and $g:Z\longrightarrow Y$, there exists a
unique function $h:Z\longrightarrow X\times Y$ such that $\pi_{X\times
> Y\longrightarrow X} \circ h=f$ and $\pi_{X\times Y\longrightarrow Y}
 \circ h=g$ (Compare this to the last part of Exercise 3.3.8, and to
Exercise 3.1.7.) This function his known as the direct sum of $f$ and
$g$ and is denoted $h = f\oplus g$.

I feel strongly that the most likley canadite for $h$ is something like $h(z):=(f(z),g(z))$. However, I don't know how to prove that this is "unique". Infact, I don't even know what uniqueness means.

Unique means there’s only one function satisfying the conditions

"Unique" isn't a property of the function. It's a property of the description of a function. For example, the square root function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is the unique function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb R$, $f(t)\ge0$ and $f(t)^2=t$. But the square root is not the unique function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(t)\ge0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. (I'm posting this answer as a comment, since this question is likely a duplicate.)

In other words, $h$ isn't "unique", it's "unique such that $\dots$ and $\dots$".

It means that if you consider two functions f,g, both satisfying the desired property, then f = g. To prove it, you consider two functions satisfying the "such that" condition. And you show that the functions are equivalent. Hint: Two functions with the same domain are equivalent iff they output the same values. You need to show that f(a) = g(a) for all a in the domain
